# Nonparametric estimation and kolmogorov sufficient statistics

Tags: information-theory, kernel-smoothing, information-criteria

Recently, I decided to revisit Cover and Thomas, and yesterday I encountered a very interesting passage in the chapter on Kolmogorov complexity:

[image]

What does this "different procedure" look like in practice?  Is it necessarily different from kernel methods, or can it be realized as a procedure for selecting kernels and bandwidths?  It seems to me that rather than a specific methodology, this is more a way to conceptualize an entire class of methodologies - but I'm not entirely sure.